# Overwrite attribute in terraform variable object

Tags: variables, terraform, hcl

I need to pass a variable that contains an object with multiple variables. Is it any way to override one of these attributes where parsing it?
For example:

> global = {
>
> ```
> region = "eu-central-1"
> account_id = "9555555"
> app_port = 8080
> domain = "my.domain"
> stage = "production"
> docker_tag = "production" }
> ```

But I want to pass this global var but with docker_tag set to "latest" is there any way to do it without the need to put all attributes and replace the one I need? (I have like 25 attributes)
Example of want i don't want to do:

> global = {
>
> ```
> region = var.region
> account_id = var.account_id
> app_port = var.app_port
> domain = var.domain
> stage = var.stage
> docker_tag = "latest" }
> ```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found myself the way to do it with merge (https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/merge.html):
"If more than one given map or object defines the same key or attribute, then the one that is later in the argument sequence takes precedence."

> merge ( var.global, { docker_tag = "latest"})

It just replaced the key I want to be replaced

Answer (score 1):

Since Terraform v1.3, you can use [Optional Object Type Attributes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes)!

Example:

```
variable "with_optional_attribute" {
  type = object({
    a = string                # a required attribute
    b = optional(string)      # an optional attribute
    c = optional(number, 127) # an optional attribute with default value
  })
}
```